# PowerShell Import-CSV "filter out blank rows" Export-CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, active-directory

I am exporting all AD user accounts, formatting into a CSV file sorted in the way management wants it. They want it sorted by the Department field and remove all accounts without a Department code listed.

I have cobbled together a script to get a formatted CSV file:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADUser -filter * -properties Name, Title, Department, SamAccountName |
    Select-Object GivenName, Surname, Title, Department |
    Export-CSV -Path "\\Server\Share\file.csv" -NoTypeInformation

'Filter only users with DEPARTMENT populated'
$BlankColumns = "Department"

Import-CSV \\JXWFILEPRD01\Les$\file.csv |
    Where-Object {
        $line = $_
        ($BlankColumns | ForEach-Object{
            ![string]::IsNullOrEmpty(($line.$_.Trim('"')))
        }) -notcontains $false
    } | Export-CSV -Path "\\Server\Share\out.csv"
```

However, when I import the CSV and remove the rows we don't want, it spills the output to the console. I have not figured out how to use `Export-CSV` in a way that works. It either errors out or continues to dump to console and then error out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do without importing/exporting multiple times and filter at the start:

```
Import-Module -Name ActiveDirectory

Get-ADUser -Filter 'Department -like "*"' -Properties Name,Title,Department,SamAccountName |
    Select-Object -Property GivenName,Surname,Title,Department |
    Sort-Object -Property Department |
    Export-CSV -Path '\\Server\Share\file.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly and I actually understand how it works! (bonus)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties Name,Title,Department,SamAccountName  | where {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace( $_.Department)} |
    Select GivenName, Surname, Title, Department | 
        Export-CSV "\\Server\Share\file.csv" -NoType
```

Comment: This does not error out, but the CSV file is empty.

Comment: Get-ADUser -filter * | where {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace( $_.Department)} print Something?

Comment: Sorry for the delay... Life happened...
I ran 
Get-ADUser -filter * | where {![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace( $_.Department)}
And it worked on something for 20 seconds or so then came back with the command prompt. So it's doing something, but no output.

Comment: ok then add -Properties Name,Title,Department,SamAccountName  (i have modified my code)